# SDL Site 9.1 Event System assembly reference issue

Tags: event-system, sites-9.1

There are sample provided by sdl to capture translation job from event system. But the reference issue with ITranslationJob Interface. Though we added all dll refference and included as mentioned in sample, but still reference issue exists.

```
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using Tridion.TranslationManager.V2;

[TcmExtension("TranslationManagerExamples.ChangingJobTitleOnSaving")]
public class ChangingJobTitleOnSaving : TcmExtension
{
    public ChangingJobTitleOnSaving()
    {
        // Subscribe on TranslationJob save event
        EventSystem.Subscribe<ITranslationJob, SaveEventArgs>(OnTranslationJobSave, EventPhases.Initiated, EventSubscriptionOrder.Normal);
    }

    private void OnTranslationJobSave(ITranslationJob subject, SaveEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
    {
        // You also can change title only once on first save if needed using SaveEventArgs.IsNewItem (e.IsNewItem). 

        if (subject.State == TranslationJobState.Definition && !subject.Title.EndsWith(" - changed"))
        {
            subject.Title = subject.Title + " - changed";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I have used below refference

1. Tridion.Common
2. Tridion.ContentManager
3. Tridion.ContentManager.Common
4. Tridion.TranslationManager.TcmExtension
5. Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.Data
6. Tridion.TranslationManager.V2.TmService

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stackexchange, please list out the reference DLLs you have already used? also update the trace error logs in your question?

Comment: Please move your comments to questions. mention with update. and leave the comment here saying that updated. also share the trace/error logs